# GroupLayout.Group class in Java

Tags: java

I'm working first time with java.swing package to create small core java project. Working in java from last two months only.

I have doubt regarding class having name "GroupLayout.Group", I'm not able to understand the syntax and is derivation of this class ?

For a test purpose when I tried to create a class like this in eclipse it shows error regarding not to create a class with this name.

Can anyone please help me to understand this ? And what should I read or approach to understand this type of class name to understand their significance and usage ?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)